# Domains and emails

Tags: email, domain, mail-server

I have bought a domain .com at hover.com and I also need and email address with that domain. Hover.com offers plans to have email addresses but they cost a lot.. And I only need one address that forwards all incoming messages to another address.

Do you have any suggestion?
Thanks

Comment: I'm using my domain for a website also.. www.mydomain.com

Answer (score 3):

You can use a free service like [**Google Apps**](http://www.google.com/apps/intl/en/group/index.html) with your domain. It allows up to 50 free addresses.

Comment: agreed. if you're not hosting a custom website or anything off of the domain, this would be the easiest / cheapest route.

Comment: I'm using my domain for a website also.. www.mydomain.com

Answer (score 0):

Most of the Domain Host Company Support Redirection of mails...
e.g. Namecheap and Godaddy. (From my personal experience, Godaddy support catch all email redirection as well)

You can redirect your mail to Gmail, and Gmail allow you to send a mail with your domain name, as long as you can confirm that you are the owner 
(They'll send a mail to you with a token and link)

You can then send and receive email with your domain.
(Thru Gmail Interface, not sure if you can send with Pop3 or Imap yet)

That's my setup on my sites.